# $http.get json with Amazon web services?

Tags: http, amazon-web-services

I am building an Angular application and all I want to do is $http.get(jsonFile) from an external service. I am thinking that Amazon Web Services could do that, which service I should you use ? Amazon Cloudfront or S3 can do that ?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront is a Content Delivery Network (CDN). It basically caches the content of a website in multiple  web servers around the world to provide faster access to users.

S3 is scalable storage, where you store files and provide access to certain users using roles.

So, you definitely don't need Cloudfront for this. You can try S3 from AWS to store your JSON files.